# Interrupt Configuration for PF4?

Tags: c, arm, cortex-m

we are going to assign priority 5 to the **Port F** then we write the following code

```
int main() { 
NVIC_PRI7_R |=0☓00A00000;  
NVIC_EN0_R= 0☓40000000;
```

My question is that where does this code `0☓00A00000` this code came from?

Answer (score 1):

The Nested Vectored Interrupt Controller (NVIC) registers are present in the [ARM Cortex M architecture](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0439b/Cihfihfe.html), so I am supposing that you are programming for that kind of target.

According to the ARM Cortex M manual:

> The NVIC supports up to 240 interrupts, each with up to 256 levels of
>   priority that can be changed dynamically.The processor and NVIC can be 
>   put into a very low-power sleep mode, leaving the Wake Up Controller
>   (WIC) to identify and prioritize interrupts.

The `NVIC_PRI7_R` variable is used to trigger the CPU in a given mode through specific registers manipulation. Setting it to a given value will make the CPU enter in a specific mode of priority (read the documentation for more).

About the `0☓00a00000`, it acts as a mask to set a few bits to '1' in `NVIC_PRI7_R`. Precisely, `0x00a00000 == 0b101000000000000000000000`, so the operation `|=` will set two bits to one and trigger the priority mode to 5 (note that `0b101 == 5`). Read the ARM Cortex M manual to see that these very precise bits trigger the priority mode of the CPU.

Hope it helped you to understand a bit more this way of doing.

Comment: Can you tell me that on what bit we put the value of 5 in order to assign the priroity 5 to the port f in 32 bit that make 0x00a00000?

0x0000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: You need to set the upper part of the third byte to the desired value, as it is done in your example.